# how to find average of maximum intensity of an image after plot a 3D surface plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I am plotting a 3D surface plot by using an image.
Below is my code:

```
x = np.arange(768)
y = np.arange(576)


X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = cv2.imread('F:\Multispectral Imaging\Readings\Different images while studying openCV\Threshold 
images\Plastics\PET\PET 460 nm\with 460 nm filter.bmp', -1)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

mycmap = plt.get_cmap('gist_earth')
ax1.set_title('gist_earth color map')
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=mycmap)
fig.colorbar(surf1, ax=ax1, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

After plotting, I see this:
[image]

I want to find out the average of the maximum intensity.
I was thinking about finding the coordinate( x and y) of the point where the intensity is maximum ( 255) and then select an area around that point ( eg: 10 * 10 pixels) and find the average of it which can give me the average intensity? Does that make sense? If it does,  How can I do that?
Also, my pixels size is 768 * 576. After plotting this 3D surface,
I use a method array = surf1.get_array()

and got something of size (2304,). Why is this size? Why not 768*576?`

Comment: What do you mean the average of the maximum?

Comment: I edited my post to give an explanation about what I want to do. Sorry for the confusion.